# Json parser from instagram api in android

Tags: android, json

```
{

"pagination": 
     {"next_max_tag_id": "AQCXof9d52l0OUMJPHt-mSJxx-p-zuH7GGDLnBv_3DhqR9LiBi8rgTw0HqAv6zHzWyar9C5_yUOmgqoZzB39OmNFELBEW7xBjkDm1tmff0RB52vJKYWt73wg61ww2XvrxCQ", 
      "next_max_id": "AQCXof9d52l0OUMJPHt-mSJxx-p-zuH7GGDLnBv_3DhqR9LiBi8rgTw0HqAv6zHzWyar9C5_yUOmgqoZzB39OmNFELBEW7xBjkDm1tmff0RB52vJKYWt73wg61ww2XvrxCQ",
       "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/love/media/recent?access_token=2121718149.3444044.98426ea4ac8445dc83aaace64b189ad2\u0026max_tag_id=AQCXof9d52l0OUMJPHt-mSJxx-p-zuH7GGDLnBv_3DhqR9LiBi8rgTw0HqAv6zHzWyar9C5_yUOmgqoZzB39OmNFELBEW7xBjkDm1tmff0RB52vJKYWt73wg61ww2XvrxCQ", 

       "next_min_id": "AQCNS5gC4sFLM5TDxwhOOBXYXU2NQGrGSaSLhPResOyHEeT5Pse_17otIZa6gpZaUFQqxNHTokaMH1ZIQt2Gbm3xur52blWeChQs3LDbqhOa8wRwFVHTVwTd79-12uWF3Ck", "min_tag_id": "AQCNS5gC4sFLM5TDxwhOOBXYXU2NQGrGSaSLhPResOyHEeT5Pse_17otIZa6gpZaUFQqxNHTokaMH1ZIQt2Gbm3xur52blWeChQs3LDbqhOa8wRwFVHTVwTd79-12uWF3Ck", 
       "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
}

, 


"data": 

      [
         {
           "id": "1592546164972439952_5948080381", 
            "user": 
                  {
                     "id": "5948080381", 
                     "full_name": "From America To Africa LDR \u2764\ufe0f", 
                      "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/21148153_1465133843555656_2623564353101627392_a.jpg", 
                      "username": "fromamericatoafrica17"
                  },


          "images": 
                  {
                     "thumbnail": 
                          {  
                              "width": 150, 
                              "height": 150, 
                              "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.78.770.770/21147744_266508440508403_5257290165033893888_n.jpg"
                          }, 
                    "low_resolution":
                          {
                              "width": 320, 
                               "height": 384, 
                           "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/p320x320/21147744_266508440508403_5257290165033893888_n.jpg"
                          }, 
                   "standard_resolution":
                           {
                                "width": 640, 
                                 "height": 769, 
                                 "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/21147744_266508440508403_5257290165033893888_n.jpg"
                           }
            }, 

         "created_time": "1504066318", 

         "caption": 
                  {
                     "id": "17890734748067049", 
                     "text": "Love it. Just love it. .\n#ldr #longdistancerelationship #puppylove #love #fromamericatoafrica", 
                     "created_time": "1504066318", 
                     "from": 
                             {
                                 "id": "5948080381", 
                                 "full_name": "From America To Africa LDR \u2764\ufe0f", 
                                 "profile_picture": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/21148153_1465133843555656_2623564353101627392_a.jpg", 
                                 "username": "fromamericatoafrica17"
                              }
                   },

        "user_has_liked": false,

         "likes": {"count": 0}, 



          "tags": 
                    [
                      "ldr", "longdistancerelationship", "love", "puppylove", "fromamericatoafrica"],



        "filter": "Normal", "comments": {"count": 0}, 

      "type": "image", 
      "link": "https://www.instagram.com/p/BYZ3Eyjl8mQ/", 
     "location": null, "attribution": null, "users_in_photo": []


      },
```

I am need to access the user name, profile picture from this json.

```
private class Insta_search extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String uri = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(uri);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(json + "\n");
                }

                return sb.toString().trim();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //PENDING_STUDENT_NAME.clear();


            if (s != null) {
                try {
                  //  JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(s);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(s)
                            .nextValue();

                    String name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
                    // DataModel mDatModel = new DataModel();
}
}
```

this my code..

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following code.

```
JsonArray responseArray = new JsonArray(response);
for(int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
    JsonObject object = responseArray.getJsonObject(i);
    JsonObject userObject = object.getJsonObject("user");
    String userName = userObject.getString("username");
    String profile_pictur = userObject.getString("profile_picture");
}
```

[Check this link for more information on Json parsing](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

Update your `onPostExecute` like:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if (s != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(s)
                    .nextValue();
            JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
            JSONObject picObj = dataArray.get(0);
            JSONObject userObj = picObj.getJSONObject("user");
            String name = userObj.getString("full_name");
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Also you have not posted complete json.

Answer (score 0):

TRy this,

```
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

    super.onPostExecute(s);

    if (s != null) 
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj =  new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray dataArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");   
            for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObj_user_data = dataArray.get(i);
                String name = jsonObj_user_data.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
                String full_name = jsonObj_user_data.getJSONObject("user").getString("full_name");
                String profile_picture = jsonObj_user_data.getJSONObject("user").getString("profile_picture");
                String username = jsonObj_user_data.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```